# Direct Sum algebraic number

Tags: field-theory

I'm doing a course in algebraic number theory and I don't understand the direct sum notation. How can the direct sum of fields be equal to a field? I thought the direct sum is a Cartesian product, where if you take the direct sum of $n$ fields, then each element of the direct sum is an $n$-tuple?

For example take a field $K$ and an element a which is algebraic over $K$ of degree $n$. Then $K(a)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n-1} K(a^i)$.

I'm very confused. If somebody can assist me here that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

The direct sum (or rather the product) of fields is not even an integral domain.

In your context, $K(\alpha)$ is the direct sum of the $K\alpha^i$s *as a $K$-vector space*.

Answer (score 1):

In your first paragraph it is a bit unclear what direct sums you are talking about. You are right that a non-trivial finite product of fields is not a field.

But the direct sum decomposition that you give as an example is one of $K$-vector spaces, not rings (resp., fields). So, more explicitly, the isomorphism preserves addition and multiplication with scalars (elements of $K$), but does not preserve multiplication.

For instance, $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q\sqrt 2.$$ (as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces)
by sending $1$ to $(1,0)$ and $\sqrt{2}$ to $(0,\sqrt{2})$. However, on the left the multiplication gives, for instance:
$$
(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2}) = 1 + 2 \sqrt{2} + 2 = 3+2\sqrt{2}.
$$
The right hand side, $\mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q\sqrt 2$, has a natural ring structure, but it is different. E.g.,
$$
(1,\sqrt{2})\cdot (1,\sqrt{2}) = (1\cdot1, \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}) = (1,2).
$$
So the isomorphism above is not an isomorphism of rings, if you consider the natural multiplication on the left hand side and the componentwise multiplication on the right hand side.

Comment: My lecture used the equal sign instead of the isomorphic sign which confused me. What is Qroot2 equal to? Is it the set of all the rational numbers multiplied by root2?

Comment: In case he uses the equal sign, it's more or less the same, only it (probably) means that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is such a direct sum. In other words: The $2$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ has a basis consisting of $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, on the right hand side of my equation $\mathbb Q\sqrt{2}$ is a one-dimensional vector space with basis element $\sqrt{2}$. I simply chose to denote this basis element by $\sqrt{2}$. I could also have written $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb Q e_1 + \mathbb Q e_2$.

But if you write equality, then you should really use elements of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ that actually form a basis; the most natural choice of which would be $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: How would you prove that the two sides are isomorphic?

Comment: In this special case, it suffices to show that the two elements $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ are a $\mathbb Q$-basis. Then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space, which is all the isomorphism says. The proof that they are linearly independent is essentially the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. To see that they span $Q(\sqrt{2})$ you should know $Q(\sqrt{2})=Q[\sqrt{2}]$ (probably you know that from your lecture; or simply check that $Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a field by hand). Any higher power of $\sqrt{2}$, can be written as a rational or rational times $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: In the general case, that you mention in your question, you have probably proved this in your lecture. (After all, this is precisely the statement that seems to confuse you.)